# If message.channel.type == "category" && message.channel.id == 'XXX' - is not working

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Good evening, all,
i want that when a message is sent, the bot checks if the message was sent in a channel of category X. If so, the code should be executed.

```
if(message.channel.type == "category" && message.channel.id == '656144179319013376'){
        //Code to be executed
    }
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't work. I also looked in the documentation and found nothing. Please help me!
- Summe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for? When the event is called, the Message is passed as an argument, the message has a field called channel. This returns the actual channel, not the category. Therefore you must get the parent of the channel to check if it's the correct one :)

```
if (message.channel.parent !== undefined && message.channel.parent.id === "categoryIDhere") {
    // Code
}
```